# POST call not working for webapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to post data in webapi for some operations . My web api contains multiple POST method.When I post data using postman it's hit to the controller method but data is passed as null.When i hit  same method from  web application it does not work and shows 404 error,

POST Call :

```
                        var urlstring = "/api/Membership/BulkUpload"
                        $.post(
                        urlstring,
                          JSON.stringify(exceljson)).

                        success(function(data)
                        {
                        console.log(data);
                        }
                        );
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpRoute("api/Membership/BulkUpload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BulkUpload([FromBody]string studentDetails)
    {
        Some Code Here
    }
```

when i remove [FromBody] then it does not hit from postman too. I am not getting what going wrong in post  call

Comment: I presume the variable exceljson is already a json and you are stringify it again? Also, try post your data as form data instead

Comment: can you me code example

Comment: var urlstring = "/api/Membership/BulkUpload"
                        $.post(
                        urlstring,
                         {
                            variable1: value1,
                            variable2: value2
                         }.

                        success(function(data)
                        {
                        console.log(data);
                        }
                        );

Comment: it's not working. I am editing a question little bit. adding : postman hitting the controller but parameter passed as null value

Comment: Maybe just try this >>> https://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/

Comment: please show value of exceljson. Is stirng or multiple properties.

Comment: Meanwhile you can use below code

var urlstring = "/api/Membership/BulkUpload"
                        $.post(
                        urlstring,
                          
                         { studentDetails: JSON.stringify(exceljson)}).

                        success(function(data)
                        {
                        console.log(data);
                        }
                        );

Comment: Is the server running in your localhost?

Comment: @Rohith : Yes...

Comment: Can you try the post call with full url instead of relative path.

Comment: @ Asif Raza : yes its a object json array

Comment: @rohith : yes i tried that too but did not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
 var urlstring = "/api/Membership/BulkUpload"
    $.post(
    urlstring,
    {JSON.stringify(exceljson))})

    .done(function(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
 );
```

Comment: Try changing the second parameter to {"hard coded string"} and can you verify in fiddler that both the postman and your ajax call are following the same url. also pls compare the request body of both.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the following:

**1 - Without [From Body]**

Client Side

```
var urlstring = `/api/Membership/BulkUpload?studentDetails=${value}`
                        $.post(
                        urlstring,
                          {}).

                        success(function(data)
                        {
                        console.log(data);
                        }
                        );


[HttpRoute("api/Membership/BulkUpload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BulkUpload(string studentDetails)
    {
        Some Code Here
    }
```

**2 - MAP to C# object**

Client Side

```
var urlstring = '/api/Membership/BulkUpload'
                        $.post(
                        urlstring,
                          {
                             studentDetails : value 
                          }).
                        success(function(data)
                        {
                        console.log(data);
                        }
                        );
```

Server Side

```
[HttpRoute("api/Membership/BulkUpload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BulkUpload([FromBody]studentApiModel dataIn)
    {
        Some Code Here
    }

 public class studentApiModel 
 {
        public string studentDetails { get; set; }
 }
```